# Proguard Plugin for SBT Not Working?

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt, proguard

```
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#xsbt-proguard-plugin;0.1.3!xsbt-proguard-plugin.jar (425ms)
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/proguard/proguard-base/4.8/proguard-base-4.8.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] net.sf.proguard#proguard-base;4.8!proguard-base.jar (1346ms)
[info] Done updating.
```

I got these messages after adding

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("sbt-plugin-releases-scalasbt", url("http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

addSbtPlugin("org.scala-sbt" % "xsbt-proguard-plugin" % "0.1.3")
```

to my `.sbt/plugins/build.sbt` file, which makes me think proguard and it's library are installed just fine. But trying to use `proguard` or checking `min-jar-path` just gives me an error

```
[error] Not a valid command: proguard (similar: reload)
```

or

```
[error] Not a valid key: min-jar-path (similar: ivy-paths)
```

I've also tried putting the same thing into the `(proj-directory)/project/build.sbt` and still no luck. Also tried putting it at `~/.sbt/plugins/plugins.sbt` with the same result. If I try `about` at the SBT prompt it tells me

```
[info] Available Plugins: ProguardPlugin
```

And yet I can't seem to run it at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step "Injecting the Plugin into desired project" is missing: https://github.com/adamw/xsbt-proguard-plugin#injecting-the-plugin-into-desired-project

Comment: wow, how embarassing, I thought those steps were for sbt 0.11 and earlier :( Thank you so much